# Finding recent Facebook friends

Tags: facebook

How to find  my recently added Facebook friends using Facebook application via fql or graph API?

Comment: Are you looking for the last 10 friends added , or friends added in the last 10 days.

Comment: actually i want to get friends added in the last 30 days.please help me.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the graph API tool:

```
SELECT created_time, description
FROM stream
WHERE source_id = me() AND type = 8
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as its 30 days it's going to be a little harder. You need to parse the users home page (http://graph.facebook.com/feed?access_token=xxx).

Once you have that you'll need to look for the story tag where the user add's a new friend. You can get the new friends details from that. The wall feed goes very far back just FYI so you'll need to handle the time as well.

Comment: sorry i can't find it,i think it is because of the story tag about friends added are deleted from the profile.Is there any method for getting  friends added in the last 10 days ?thanks for your response.

Comment: It's definitely still there. You'll need to trawl through someones posts to find when they added a friend. As an alternative you could also use the search API once you find the relevant JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to make an application like Facebook Mapper.
This application is a very useful application for those who want to retrieve the facebook friends. 
You can use it for access to a facebook profile. There is a chrome extension for the same. This is named as `[Facebook Mapper Chrome][1]`

Hope this will help you